# Read-Only Pods in Openshift

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline, openshift

I am trying to implement Read-Only filesystems for my Pods running on Openshift.

I use Jenkins to build and deploy these pods in Openshift.

For Build, I use :

```
def builddemo = openshift.newBuild("${Image}~${Github}", "--name=${Name}",  "--source-secret=githubsecret", "--to=${artifactorylocation}", "--push-secret=artifactorysecret", "--to-docker=true" , "--strategy=docker")
```

For Deploy, I use YAML files.

I would like to make my filesystem read-only.

I have already tried below document :

https://github.com/nmasse-itix/OpenShift-Examples/tree/master/Read-Only-FS

But, I dont have admin privileges on the cluster to change security config. I only have admin privileges in my own namespace.

```
from server for: "read-only-scc.yaml": securitycontextconstraints.security.openshift.io "readonly-fs" is forbidden: User "USERNAME" cannot get securitycontextconstraints.security.openshift.io at the cluster scope: no RBAC policy matched
```

Is there anyway, I can do it.

Comment: I'm curious about why you'd need to do this. To be honest, I don't know the answer -- but it's a question that rarely arises. The usual way to protect a pod's filesystem from processes in the pod is to run those processes as a user that has no write permissions on the files. You don't need cluster admin permission for that -- it's just a matter of how you build your container image.

Comment: It's not about protecting the files. But about the disk usage. Our prod cluster has very limited physical space available and I don't want my pods to grow over time, so I want to make them read-only. Though in my Dockerfile, the user has no write permissions on the application files but I am concerned about other directories which might grow over time.

Comment: Which directories might these be? If your application can't write, what can? Making a pod's filesystem read-only at the platform level is, I think, I fairly unusual step.

Comment: Not any directory specifically. But any directory which might use disk space of underlying hosts. Yes, My application doesn't write ... May be some logs. Its is just an caution step to avoid outage. But I agree to your point. I am thinking of monitoring my filesystems for increase in usage over time and if it happens then need to debug that. But I thought may be there is an easier way to make everything read-oinly,.